# How to encode path parameter using Java Jersey

Tags: java, url, encoding, jersey

How do you encode a path parameter (not form-url-encoded) but just a single URL that's appended in the format:

```
public String method(@PathParam("url") String url) {
}
```

There are lots of references to form URL encoding, but I want to simply encode a string as in the above.

Comment: Can you please clarify what it is you're trying to do and the problem you're having? A code example would be nice. Your question doesn't make a lot of sense as is.

Comment: sorry. What I meant is that how do I encode the path parameter in the client when calling the server resource method above for a GET not POST? The URL for a single domain retrieval for this resource is /api/urls/{url}. I understand for a POST form encoding occurs automatically but for a GET I believe this isn't so?

Comment: See Dave's answer below. You use the [URLEncoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) class.

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in the previous answer `URLEncoder` can only be used for query paramaters, not path parameters. This matters e.g. for spaces which are a `+` in the query parameter but a `%20` in the path.

```
 org.springframework.web.util.UriUtils.encodePath()
```

can be used. Also using an `org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder` would work. `setPath` is escaping the path part here. Also pure Java by using a constructor of `java.net.Uri` works.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to *en*code it there, if anything wouldn't you want to *de*code it? In any case, you would call the standard [URLEncoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html).

Comment: No, you wouldn't. `URLEncoder` is suitable for encoding query, matrix, and form parameters, but not path parameters. See, for example, https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-417